# Connecting Liferay to SQL Server Database

Tags: sql-server, liferay

So I'm trying to connect to our SQL Server Database via the portal-ext.properties, but before I do I want to make sure I do it correctly.

I'm confused as to what goes in place of "localhost" and "/lportal"

```
jdbc.default.driverClassName=net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.default.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost/lportal
jdbc.default.username=my_user
jdbc.default.password=my_password
```

Do I replace localhost with my site's url? and Do I keep lportal as is?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jdbc.default.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://localhost/lportal
```

**Shold be something like this**

```
jdbc.default.url=jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://"Sql Server hostname here"/"database name here"
```

**And also you can specify the port if is diferent from default !! 1433 !**

**With the port should be like :**

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://"Sql Server hostname here":"port nr"/"database name here"
```

Comment: Thank you very much Up_One (cool name)! I'm not sure what my database name would be exactly?

Comment: Ok - in Sql Server you have and instance(the sql server installation - holds the System databases) and the Databases(called schemas in Oracle - You create a database and to be populated by your application or website). - Is this what you ask ?

Comment: One last question. Could it also be written this way? jdbc.default.url=jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:58190;databaseName=lportal

Answer (score 1):

[image: Maybe this picture will explain better- where A are your databases!]

Maybe this picture will explain better- where A are your databases

Comment: Jut for the future you can follow this link for more details and how to's LINK - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378428.aspx